# Visual Studio does not create output directory

Tags: visual-studio-2008, directory, creation

I have the following lines in the VCLinkerTool section of my project:

```
OutputFile="$(OutDir)\bin\engine.dll"

ImportLibrary="$(OutDir)\lib\engine.lib"

ProgramDatabaseFile="$(OutDir)\pdb\engine.pdb"

StripPrivateSymbols="$(OutDir)\pbs\engine.pdb"
```

The directories "bin", "lib", and "pdb" are automatically created in the `$(OutDir)` directory, but the "pbs" directory is not.

Any ideas about why this is happening?  I have no custom-, pre-, or post-build sections.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not [stripping private symbols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y87kw2fd.aspx) from your PDBs.

You need to explicitly set this up in the property pages (Linker -> Debug) if you want `pbs` versions of your PDB files.

Comment: That was how I got that tag in the project file.

Comment: Note that if I create the $(OutDir)/pbs directory manually before I do the build, the stripped PDB file is created correctly.

Comment: @Rob - In that case, I would guess this is a permissions issue.